# ProcessBuilder for tests with fail cases

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, processbuilder

I faced the problem of writing unit tests using the `ProcessBuilder`. I'm using the `Mockito (1.10.19)` for creating mock objects. The main problem there is `Mockito` can't mock final classes.

```java
   public final class ProcessBuilder
```

But I need to test failed cases where `ProcessBuilder` returns such `Process` which always returns zero exit code.
For this reason, I'm looking for a `Process` that always returns a non-zero value in any OS (any test environment).

```java
   ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("<always failed command>");
   Process process = processBuilder.start();
   final int exitCode = process.waitFor();
   assert exitCode != 0;
```

Does anyone know such an *always failed command*? Or, maybe, a better way to test fail cases with the `ProcessBuilder`?

Comment: You could try to list a non-existent file. Running on **nix? The shell command `false` should do it for you.

Comment: With linux, you can just use the command `false`. With windows, you could try to use `cmd /c exit 0` or something like this.

Comment: @dan1st sorry - didn't see your earlier comment about `false`

Comment: @dan1st, thank you. I checked It works perfectly with Linux.  But I'm not sure it will work with Windows. Also, to be honest,  I'm don't want to write code for detecting OS.

Comment: Use a wrapper object for the `ProcessBuilder`. It should be work with `Mockito`.

Comment: Perhaps `new ProcessBuilder("whoami", "--invalidoption")`?

Comment: As @ThiloSchwarz said, just because you are ultimately calling ProcessBuilder doesn't mean that the code you are testing has to have a dependency on it. Write a wrapper and mock the wrapper.